# Date Ranges into Monthly Breakdown

Tags: sql, date, teradata

Hi I have a SQL question, I'm trying to get end of month records for each person within a certain date range. Essentially I want this record to be tracking historically (years worth of data) using some sort of End of Month record if their start and end dates fall within the last day of each month. So the data currently looks like this (using just 2022 for simplicity)..

| Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2022-01-15 | 2022-04-10 |
| Jane Doe | 2022-01-18 | 2022-03-05 |
| Rob Johnson | 2022-03-07 | 2022-07-18 |

And what I'm looking for is something like this

| Name | StartDate | EndDate | EndMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2022-01-15 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-01-31 |
| Jane Doe | 2022-01-18 | 2022-03-05 | 2022-01-31 |
| John Smith | 2022-01-15 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-02-28 |
| Jane Doe | 2022-01-18 | 2022-03-05 | 2022-02-28 |
| John Smith | 2022-01-15 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-03-31 |
| Rob Johnson | 2022-03-07 | 2022-07-18 | 2022-03-31 |
| Rob Johnson | 2022-03-07 | 2022-07-18 | 2022-04-30 |
| Rob Johnson | 2022-03-07 | 2022-07-18 | 2022-05-31 |

etc...

I tried connecting the **Records** table with a **Calendar** table i have that has End of Month data for each day for several years back but can't figure this out. The Calendar table looks something like this..

| Date | EndMonth |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-31 |
| ..... |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOINing two tables should give the desired result.

---

You didn't mention a table name for your initial table,
so I will refer to it as the `person` table.

Your `calendar` table is a good start.
I don't believe you need the Date column.
Just a single EndMonth column should suffice.

---

JOIN person against calendar,
WHERE EndMonth BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate.

And you're done!

---

OP reports that this works fine:

```
SELECT P.Name, P.StartDate, P.EndDate, C.EndMonth
FROM PERSON P, CALENDAR C
WHERE EndMonth BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just a question.. do i join the Calendar Table based on the start date or the end date? Also, the joining to the Calendar table doesn't give me the monthly intervals.. if for example i join it the Start date.. the between clause will give me just the record for the end of month for that start day month and not subsequent months. what i have is this..
SELECT
A.Name,
A.StartDate,
A.EndDate,
B.EndMonth
FROM PERSON A
JOIN CALENDAR B ON
B.Date  = A. StartDate
WHERE MonthDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;

Comment: You almost have it. Now, it is _often_ the case that we want an ON clause when JOINing, so as to avoid an accidental Cartesian cross product. But here, the cross product is exactly what we want. And then the WHERE will prune out most of those rows, leaving just the BETWEEN matches. So use that query you suggested, but without the ON clause. (Also, rather than arbitrary aliases A & B, you might prefer P & C.)

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much.. My final code that works is..
SELECT P.Name, P.StartDate, P.EndDate, C.EndMonth FROM PERSON P, CALENDAR C WHERE (EndMonth BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate);

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is exactly what the Teradata's proprietary EXPAND ON syntax is used for, no need for a calendar table:

```
SELECT 
   t.*
  ,pd        -- EXPAND ON returns a period 
  ,begin(pd) -- only show the start of the period
FROM records AS t
-- create a period on-the-fly, adjust the end date as periods exclude the end
EXPAND ON PERIOD(StartDate, Next(EndDate)) AS pd
       BY ANCHOR MONTH_END -- return one row per month
```